# Find highest threshold across 5 columns of dataframe to obtain n records

Tags: r, function, dataframe, minimax

So I have a dataframe of 5 columns with 9031 observations.  Each record of a column is a the percentile rank of all the values in the column.

My goal is to find the highest percentile threshold to apply to all five columns in order to obtain n records.

So for example let's say my goal is to reduce to the number of records in my dataframe to 1000 records, what is the highest threshold I need to apply to all 5 columns in order to obtain 1000 records?

```
  Variance_Five_Metrics$Zips    medium  medium.1  medium.2  medium.3   medium.4
  1                      00501 0.8395527 0.8671243 0.9894807 0.6567379 0.45875318
  2                      00544 0.8075518 0.8687853 0.9883734 0.6345920 0.45100210
  3                      01432 0.6124460 0.2460414 0.9701030 0.9103089 0.17107740
  4                      01434 0.7869560 0.3000775 0.9268077 0.8760935 0.11859152
  5                      01450 0.6642675 0.2451556 0.9919167 0.9585871 0.09600266
```

So let's say the above if the first five records (of 9031 records) of my dataframe. If I want to shrink my df to exactly 1000 records, what is the cutoff point I need to apply to all 5 columns in order to obtain exactly 1000 records where all 5 columns have values below this cutoff point?

I probably didn't explain this that well, but I'd appreciate any guidance

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the cutoff point has to be the same for all the 5 columns or one cutoff value per individual colum?

Comment: cutoff point must be the same for all 5 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question right then you can achieve this with a simple row-wise minimum. Here is a line to obtain the cut-off value:

```
quantile(apply(MAT, 1, min), p=1-(100/nrow(MAT)))
```

You would need to replace "100" with your own number of wanted rows.

---

Short explanation below

So let's say you have a matrix of 5 columns:

```
MAT <- matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol=5)
```

You want to find a value that after cutoff on all columns together will leave you 100 rows:

```
n <- 100
```

In order to for whole row to be included all 5 of it's columns need to be above the cut-off value. This is the same as asking for the minimum value of that row to be above the cut-off.

```
MIN <- apply(MAT, 1, min)
```

Now we can find a percentile for cutoff.

```
p <- 1 - (n/length(MIN))
```

You want 100 values so the above is simply 1 - 100/1000 which is 0.9. So your cutoff will be >= 0.9 percentile.

get the percentile:

```
q <- quantile(MIN, probs=p)
```

Did it work?

```
sum(MAT[,1] > q & MAT[,2] > q & MAT[,3] > q & MAT[,4] > q & MAT[,5] > q)
[1] 100
```

Comment: I believe this is close, but each record is already a quantile, so would I just need to take the last step?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if is exactly what you are looking for. I sum the columns, take the top `n` number and then provide the minimum parameters for that subset.

```
GetThresholds<-function(data,n){
  data$summed<-rowMeans(data[,2:6])
  data<-data[order(-data$summed),]
  data.small<-head(data,n=n)
  output<- c(min(data.small[,2]),
             min(data.small[,3]),
             min(data.small[,4]),
             min(data.small[,5]),
             min(data.small[,6]))
  names(output)<-names(data)[2:6]
  return(output)
}


GetThresholds(df,3)
> GetThresholds(df,3)
medium   medium.1   medium.2   medium.3   medium.4 
0.7869560 0.3000775 0.9268077 0.6345920 0.1185915
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, sorry for my lack of specificty this is almost what I want but I want a uniform threshold for all 5 columns if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

An example using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- read.table(
  header = TRUE,
  text = "
zips    medium  medium.1  medium.2  medium.3   medium.4
00501 0.8395527 0.8671243 0.9894807 0.6567379 0.45875318
00544 0.8075518 0.8687853 0.9883734 0.6345920 0.45100210
01432 0.6124460 0.2460414 0.9701030 0.9103089 0.17107740
01434 0.7869560 0.3000775 0.9268077 0.8760935 0.11859152
01450 0.6642675 0.2451556 0.9919167 0.9585871 0.09600266
")

cutoff <- 3 # number of rows to keep (change to 1000 for your example)

d %>%
  mutate(p_min = pmin(medium, medium.1, medium.2, medium.3, medium.4)) %>%
  arrange(p_min) %>%
  .$p_min %>%
  '['(., cutoff)
```